# Is there a CLI tool to view a single transaction from a Cardano node, e.g. local-cluster or prod?

Tags: transaction-metadata, linux, tools, inline-datum

Cardanoscan is great for testnet/pre-prod/mainnet. There are also some great tools like Oura for viewing transactions as they are happening, but some of the information in the transaction isn't showing.

Given a single (known) transaction ID, and a running Cardano node, is there a CLI tool for Linux for viewing the contents of a transaction, i.e. including metadata and inline datum, that works as easily as Oura, but has the detail of Cardanoscan?

Comment: It is always good to include link of the knowledge provided, this way other people that have the same question or that are responding to it, have clear examples of what you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kupo](https://github.com/CardanoSolutions/kupo) may do what you want. Else check for alternatives in its readme.

Comment: Kupo is certainly easier to setup than some of the options. I am just looking at it now. In terms of user expectations here, is the answer always, that one needs to run a local indexer to view transaction data? Even when running a Cardano node, there's no random access to the information on it, so to speak?

Comment: @ross-spencer It is non-trivial to get historical transaction data using the node's mini protocols. Chain-followers (indexers) such as kupo and marconi stream this data out so  you just need to query a rest api or sql db for useful and well formatted transaction data. They also handle rollbacks. Your alternative to a local indexer is something like blockfrost.

Comment: Thanks @james. I've marked this as the correct answer as it is working for my use-case. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, as the Cardano node stores only the current state of the blockchain without any historical data, which transactions are.

Comment: I appreciate this clear answer, and it's helpful to have this confirmed for a newbie. I need additional rep to vote it up, but here's a vote in spirit anyway!